# Gap between elements at various zoom levels

Tags: html, css

```css
#sidebar {
  width: 160px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #ed1b2e;
  position: absolute;
  top: 57px;
  left: 0;
}
#sidebar .inner {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f35765;
  padding: 0px 0;
}
#sidebar .list {
  padding: 20px 0 15px;
}
#sidebar .list li {
  padding: 4px 0;
}
#sidebar .list a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#sidebar .list a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
#sidebar .list a.active {
  background: #000810;
  position: relative;
}
#sidebar .list a.active:hover {
  background-color: #000810;
  background-color: rgba(0, 8, 16, 0.9);
}
#sidebar .list a.active:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  right: -30px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: #000810;
  border-width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar" style="min-height: 1586px;">
  <div class="sidebar-wrap">
    <div class="sidebar-content">
      <div class="inner">
        <ul id="MAIN_TAB_2000_SUBMENU_TOP" class="list" style="">
          <li>
            <a id="2020" href="/service/main.do" class="active">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a id="2022" href="/service/sales/documents/issues.do">Document issues</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //sidebar-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- //sidebar-wrap -->
</div>
```

If user in Chrome changes Zoom to for example 90% then Black arrow separates into two pieces. I want black arrow to be always look like when it is on 100%. I want black arrow to be always look like when it is on 100%. Any suggestions? [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/mLwk4stt/)

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. It is for a good reason! The questions need to be self contained so that they will always be guaranteed to have context. If a link dies then the question can become pointless and of no value to other users experiencing a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid this problem by positioning your arrow using `left: 100%;` instead of `right: -30px;`.

- Remove `right: -30px;` from `#sidebar .list a.active:after`
- Add `left: 100%;` to `#sidebar .list a.active:after`

My best guess as to why this is happening is that this is probably due to the way the browser is rounding pixel values.

```css
#sidebar {
  width: 160px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #ed1b2e;
  position: absolute;
  top: 57px;
  left: 0;
}
#sidebar .inner {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f35765;
  padding: 0px 0;
}
#sidebar .inner.inner-top {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
#sidebar .inner.no-border {
  border-bottom: none;
}
#sidebar .selector-holder {
  padding: 25px 18px 28px 18px;
}
#sidebar .selector {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
#sidebar .selector .toggler {
  display: block;
  outline: 0;
  height: 28px;
  background: #cc1626;
  padding: 0 25px 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 28px;
}
#sidebar .selector .toggler span {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar .selector .toggler:after {
  top: 50%;
  right: 8px;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  margin-top: -2px;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 6px;
  margin-left: -6px;
}
#sidebar .selector .toggler.hidden:after {
  display: none;
}
#sidebar .selector ul {
  padding: 3px 0;
}
#sidebar .selector ul li {
  padding: 2px 0;
}
#sidebar .selector ul a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #ffffff;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#sidebar .selector ul a:hover,
#sidebar .selector ul a.active {
  background: #9c9c9c;
}
#sidebar .js-dropdown-content {
  min-width: 100%;
  background: #808080;
}
#sidebar .list {
  padding: 20px 0 15px;
}
#sidebar .list li {
  padding: 4px 0;
}
#sidebar .list a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#sidebar .list a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
#sidebar .list a.active {
  background: #000810;
  position: relative;
}
#sidebar .list a.active:hover {
  background-color: #000810;
  background-color: rgba(0, 8, 16, 0.9);
}
#sidebar .list a.active:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: #000810;
  border-width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar" style="min-height: 1586px;">
  <div class="sidebar-wrap">
    <div class="sidebar-content">
      <div class="inner">
        <ul id="MAIN_TAB_2000_SUBMENU_TOP" class="list" style="">
          <li>
            <a id="2020" href="/service/main.do" class="active">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a id="2022" href="/service/sales/documents/issues.do">Document issues</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //sidebar-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- //sidebar-wrap -->
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

Why do you want to see you page in 90% zoom. try to code your web page in 100%.
it is obvious when you zoom your page the pixel will distort.